# Android Launcher application compilation on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, homescreen, launcher

I am modifying the Android Home (Launcher) application and configured an eclipse project from the Android source checkout. Eclipse project shows number of errors which are about unresolved imports and unavailable flags. Upon checking in the internet at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=8402045 , I found that the home application will not compile with the public SDK, but as part of the OS compilation, it is generated.

My question is how can I resolve the compilation errors in my eclipse project? Have anyone faced this public SDK and home application compilation issue?

I want to be able to build my Launcher.apk right from eclipse and run it.

Comment: Can we have some private SDK (atleast Android.jar) to enable the compilation and who can provide that? I have checked in the Android build folder but nowhere it is found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this thread to have more informations:
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/cc8f4b3de53599b7

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can I resolve the compilation errors in my eclipse project?

You don't. You can only build the Launcher application as part of the full firmware.

> I want to be able to build my Launcher.apk right from eclipse and run it.

That is not possible, sorry. There is as sample Home application in your SDK that can be built from the SDK, though, if that helps.

Comment: At least I want to resolve my eclipse errors so that I can make effective use of all the features of eclipse including organizing imports, code generation, Syntax checking etc ...